# How to perform multiplication for integers larger than 64 bits in C++ and VHDL?

Tags: c++, vhdl

I want to multiply a 57-bit integer with an 11-bit integer. The result can be up to 68 bits so I'm planning to split my result into 2 different integers. I cannot use any library and It should be as simple as possible because the code will be translated to VHDL.

There is some way to that online but all of them are not meet my criteria. I want to split the result as an 60-bit lower part and an 8-bit higher part.

### C++

```
int main() {
    unsigned long long int log2 = 0b101100010111001000010111111101111101000111001111011110011;
    unsigned short int absE;
    unsigned in result_M;
    unsigned long long int result_L;

    result_L = absE * log2;
    result_M = 0;
}
```

### VHDL

```
signal absE : std_logic_vector(10 downto 0);
signal log2 : std_logic_vector(57 downto 0) := "101100010111001000010111111101111101000111001111011110011";
signal result: std_logic_vector(67 downto 0);
result <= absE * log2;
```

Comment: You say "I cannot use any library". I don't see why not. To solve your prblem, code needs to be written. Why does it matter whether that code is written by you or by someone else (and provided to you in library form)? In the end it's just a chunk of code. Shouldn't matter who wrote it. Btw; using [GMP](https://gmplib.org) is one easy way to solve your problem.

Comment: @JesperJuhl *the code will be translated to VHDL* might have something to do with it.

Comment: VHDL - multiplication is done different way

Comment: GCC and some other compilers have 128 bit integers as extensions.  In GCC you could use `__int128`.  Never use pre-C99 integer types of you don't have a good reason, they might bite you.

Comment: Oh, `log2()` is a standard function. Probably not a good idea to use the name for a variable.

Comment: The multiplicands should be as long as the result, or a cast should be used before the multiplication.  If not, the result will be truncated.

Comment: Why did you tag C++?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito He's using a C++ style signature for `main()` and a binary integer literal (Standard in C++, not C). Better questio might be why did he tag C?

Comment: @Shawn  So true, so true.  :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the mess. Actually I'm using C and writing the code for a part of a project which aims high-level synthesis of C based descriptions. So, less library is better and shoter integers are better for the project. Thanks a lot for the huge help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the 57-bit value into smaller chunks to perform the multiplications and recombine into the required parts, for example 8+49 bits:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
#define MASK(n)  ((1ULL << (n)) - 1)
    uint64_t log2 = MASK(57);                     // 57 bits
    uint16_t absE = MASK(11);                     // 11 bits
    uint32_t m1 = (log2 >> 49) * absE;            // middle 19 bits at offset 49;
    uint64_t m0 = (log2 & MASK(49)) * absE + ((m1 & MASK(11)) << 49); // low 61 bits
    uint16_t result_H = (uint16_t)(m1 >> 11) + (uint16_t)(m0 >> 60); // final high 8 bits
    uint64_t result_L = m0 & MASK(60);

    printf("%#"PRIx64" * %#"PRIx16" = %#"PRIx16"%012"PRIx64"\n",
           log2, absE, result_H, result_L);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `0x1ffffffffffffff * 0x7ff = 0xffdfffffffffff801`

You may need more steps if you cannot use the 64-bit multiplication used for the 49-bit by 11-bit step.

Comment: Why would you cast C99 types to pre-C99 types. Better use `PRIx64` from `<inttypes.h>`

Comment: @CacahueteFrito: OK, I was just being lazy.

Answer (score 0):

VHDL is different than C - here you have the paper how to implement multiplication. Expand it to as many bits as you need:

http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~nelsovp/courses/elec4200/Slides/VHDL%207%20Multiplier%20Example.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In GCC:

```
__int128 a;
__int128 b;
__int128 c;
uint64_t c_lo;
uint8_t c_hi;

a = 0x789;
b = 0x123456789ABCDEF;
c = a * b;

c_lo = (uint64_t)c & ((UINT64_C(1) << 60) - 1);
c_hi = (unsigned __int128)c >> 60;
```

You will need the standard library for this.  You will need the header file `<stdint.h>` (`<cstdint>` in C++), but that shouldn't be a problem when translating into VHDL.

Comment: This is the easiest solution, but only if the VHDL compiler supports 128-bit integers

Answer (score 0):

if you (or every wants who wants) are not dealing with arbitrary length you can use a library like this: [int512.h](https://github.com/Luquitasjeffrey/int512.h/blob/main/int512.h)